# How do I use .lib to compile and link in c++ builder 11.3 windows 64bits platform?

Tags: c++, 64-bit, c++builder, rad-studio

I want to compile and link .lib files within C++ Builder 11.3 using the Windows 64-bit platform, but it only allows me to select .a files. How can I proceed to compile and link .lib files for the Windows 64-bit platform?

Comment: Where are you getting those `.lib` files from? You _are_ aware that statically-linked library files don't have an ABI and so are non-portable and therefore compiler-specific?

Comment: Apaparently, C++Builder _can_ work with MSVC `.lib` files, including those for Win32, but some tricks are required: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76992805/how-to-use-static-library-libsodium-lib-in-cbuilder

Comment: @Dai My .lib file is from MSVC x64 compile.  C++ biilder's 64bit windows platform can only add .a file. 32bit's platform is normal. So I want to know how to use the 64bit .lib file in the 64bit windows platform.

Comment: @Dai Nothing in the other question you linked to suggests that C++Builder can use MSVC lib files by using "some tricks". There are no such tricks. If you read what the comments actually say on it, the OP was instructed to create *new*  lib files that are specific for C++Builder.

Comment: @xyLi you cannot use MSVC lib files in C++Builder (and vice versa). If the libs are DLL import libs, you can create new libs using C++Builder's own tools. But if the libs are static libraries, you are SOL unless you have their source code and can recompile them in C++Builder .

Comment: @RemyLebeau My issue is that I cannot include .lib files for compilation; I can only include .a files. Let's not worry about whether the architecture can compile correctly for now.

Comment: @xyLi you still have not stated what the nature of the libs are. See my earlier comments. Are they DLL import libs, or are they static libs? It makes a BIG difference.

Comment: @RemyLebeau oh, sorry. 
The nature of .lib is a static library. On the Windows 64-bit platform, when a .lib file is included, it will appear gray (black in 32-bit). However, during linking, the .lib file is not included. I have tested with .a files, and they do contain linker directives.

Comment: @xyLi You cannot use MSVC static libs in any non-MSVC compiler. Static libs are compiler-specific files.  So your only option is to either 1) recompile the libs source code using the C++Builder compiler, or 2) wrap the static libs inside a DLL written in MSVC and then use that DLL in your C++Builder code