# How to build a Windows 64-bit platform static library (.lib) using C++ Builder 11 instead of .a file?

Tags: c++, c++builder, rad-studio

How to build a Windows 64-bit platform static library (.lib) using C++ Builder 11 instead of .a file?

[image]

And then use that static library (.lib) to build my program on the Windows 64-bit platform.
[image]

Comment: You can't.  The C++ 64bit compiler requires `.a` files for static libraries. This is [documented](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/BCC64). This seems to be just a continuation of your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78213909/)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you, you finally understand what I'm asking. I finally understand that 64-bit cannot use .lib files.